# Is reading config file at android app start a security issue?

Tags: android, security, configuration-files

a senior colleague of mine is so against hitting the server for a config file at app boot. he claims it's a security issue and should not happen regardless on what we want to read from there. could you help me with some pros/cons?

by a config file I mean:

- this file will have some flag for the app to know what features are supposed to be on/off. e.g. streaming vs progressive-download.
- this file can have links to some static content e.g. privacy policy, EULA, etc and maybe even link to some of the APIs like analytic API that we use for reporting app usage.

and if the server is not accessible, we use the default/most recent downloaded config file.

He sort of doesn't explain his concerns. I guess he is mostly concerned about man-in-the-middle attack.

Comment: I recommend that you edit your question to explain your situation in **much greater detail**: what is in this file, what your app does with the information, what you plan to do if you do not have server access, what your colleague is *specifically* concerned about, etc.

Comment: @CommonsWare, please let me know if you think the question still needs more detail.

Comment: MITM attacks cannot be performed if you are using SSL (unless your company's server gets compromised). You have to make a few tweaks in the app to make it only accept the certificates of your company, but other than that it should be fine. The only problem that I could see is denial of service, but you have to update the clients somehow anyway if this data is dynamic. Is this info that you are sending supposed to be confidential?

Comment: Perhaps you need https://firebase.google.com/features/remote-config/

Comment: As jackgu1988 indicates, given SSL with some degree of certificate pinning, what you are doing does not seem too outrageous. For added protection, you could wrap the config file in a container that can be digitally signed, then validate the signature to ensure that the contents of the container have not been tampered with (and match the expected signing key).